# Rails nested routing to html id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

given a blog style application:

```
#models
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

#routes.rb
map.resources :posts do |posts|
  posts.resources :comments
end
```

how do I generate routes to an id on a page? Examples

```
/posts/1#comments
/posts/2#comment14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the routes generate methods for anchors like that, but you can add anchors into the url generators for posts.

```
 post_path(@post, :anchor => "comments")
 post_path(@post, :anchor => "comment#{@comment_id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this was to generate the path to the comment show action which then redirected to the anchor via the method erik posted.